# Integration for Force of Lever

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Archimedes' original computation of the area below a parabolic arc relied on a clever argument based on the law of the lever from physics. The law of the lever states that the force exerted on a lever by a given mass is proportional to the mass times the distance from the mass to the fulcrum.

A) Consider the interval $x ∈ [a,b]$ as a rod of variable density $ρ(x)$. Let c be any point in $[a,b]$ and imagine the entire $x$-axis as a lever, with fulcrum $c$. The part of the rod to the right of $c$ exerts force on the lever. Explain why this force is approximated by:

[image]

as $N→∞$. Write a definite integral for this force.

B) Likewise, write a definite integral for the force applied to the lever form the part of the rod from $x = a$ to $x = c$. Write a single definite integral for the total force applied to the lever.

C) Under what conditions will the rod balance perfectly at $x = c$? [Note: the point $c$ is called the center of the mass of the rod.]

D) Find the center of the mass of the rod over [0,1] with density function: ρ(x)= $x^2$+1.

$$\\$$This is what I have so far:

PART A: density of the rod varies: $x$ or $ρ=ρ(x)$

$c$: fulcrum, $N$: number of segments on the right side of the fulcrum, $i$: counter of segments

length of part on the right: $b - c$, length of each segment: $\frac{(b - c)}{N}$

distance between $i^{th}$ segment and fulcrum: $\frac{i(b - c)}{N}$.
i.e $(x-c)$

I noticed that $c + \frac{i(b - c)}{N}$ = $c+(x-c) = x$

So, for $i^{th}$ piece to the right: moment = force * distance from lever

also $ρ$ is considered to be weight per unit length

Moment = $\sum^{i=0}_{N}ρ (c + \frac{i(b - c)}{N})(\frac{i(b - c)}{N})$.

I don't know how to go about writing the definite integral for the force. & I'm confused with how to go about Part B, C, and D. Please help.